# Generating a cache busting key in Plone based on the process start-up timestamp

Tags: python, plone

I am exporting data read and generated during a web server process start-up. The lifetime of this data is the duration of a web server process run (or: you need to restart the web server to enter any new data offline).

I'd like a add a cache busting parameter to the HTML links pointing to the data download view. Effectively it should be a unique randomish number depending on the process start-up timestamp or similar process unique parameter.

What's the best way to get the process start-up timestamp or similar unique identifier in a Plone or Python process generally?

Comment: This is going to be difficult if you have multiple zeo clients running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not generate a new ID in your python product? At the module level, define a new random constant on module load:

```
import random

RANDOMID = random.randit(0, 1<<32)
```

and use that.

Comment: This won't work because each zeo client will have a different cache key.

Comment: @vangheem It really doesn't matter as long as the cache can be invalidated

Comment: @Martjin: Also figured out import time ; SEED = time.time() works after we thought last night